# JPEG file SOS marker before SOF

Tags: obfuscation, steganography

I'm looking over some JPEG files with an assumption that a steganography has been used for trial obfuscation due to the installation of *JPHS*.

I've come across a file where the start of scan marker precedes the start of frame.  Should this file be further inspected?

[image]

Comment: Do be aware that this can also indicate a corrupted JPG, though it's certaintly worth a shot looking at them if you're expecting something.